# Create multiple array

Tags: arrays, laravel-8

I have multple array like this

```
        MaritalStatus" => "single"
                "CollateralType" => array:2 [▼
                0 => "Car"
                1 => "Shamba"
                ]
                "CollateralStatus" => array:2 [▼
                0 => "Best Condition"
                1 => "Best Condition"
                ]
                "GuarantorName" => array:3 [▼
                0 => "Minja"
                1 => "Minja"
                2 => "Minja"
                ]
                "GuarantorNumber" => array:3 [▼
                0 => "09736646"
                1 => "09736646"
                2 => "09736646"
                ]
                ]
```

I have tried to `loop` like this and does not created all array and second array

```
      foreach($request->CollateralType as $key=>$dt){

                  'CollateralStatus'=>$request->CollateralType[$key],

                  'CollateralStatus'=>$request->CollateralStatus[$key],
                   'GuarantorNumber'=>$request->GuarantorNumber[$key],
                    'GuarantorName'=>$request->GuarantorName[$key],
                  .......
              }
```

How can i loop and create all array in one time

Comment: What do you mean with loop and create all array? Would you clarify your question ?

Comment: I mean that how can i loop that request array and create to the database.

Comment: Try to see `foreach loop`